# Using 'by' when comparing changes in size, amount, number, etc

Tags: prepositions, comparison

I am so confused when it comes to prepositions used with words that show trends.
For instance, my teacher gave me these examples:

> Canada made up 618,9 kWh of electricity produced and by almost 100 kWh
> less of that consumed.
>
> Other sources brought only 38 million in 2017
> and just 1 million more in 2018.
>
> Most of the students (30%) spoke
> Spanish, while 10% fewer students did not speak any other language
> than English.

I can't get it why it is 'by N less' in the first example, but 'N more' and 'N fewer' in the second and the third.
Could anybody please explain to me when we use 'by' and when we don't when describing that things changed by a certain value?

Comment: By indicates amount..

Comment: The first sentence is terrible. It's almost nonsense (although you might be able to make sense of the figures if the context is adequate). I would advise you to completely ignore it as a model for correct English.

Comment: Actually, the third sentence is also rubbish. Suppose you have 100 students: What it is saying is that 30% of students (30 students) spoke Spanish, while 10% fewer (i.e. 10 % of the 30 = 3 , thus 3 fewer = 27 students) only spoke English. In reality it's impossible to work out what he or she really intended.

Comment: @PRL75, the idea was to say that 30% of students spoke Spanish and 20% spoke English only. How would you say then - out of 1000 students, 30% (= 300 students) spoke Spanish and by 10% fewer (= 200) students spoke English?

Comment: This question needs clearer examples with good English before it can be answered.

Comment: "*I am so confused … my teacher gave me these examples*".  Well there's your problem right there. Your teacher is giving you examples of very bad English. They would confuse anyone.  I suspect that you already understand the language better than your teacher.

Comment: @ArsenyAleev says "*he idea was to say that 30% of students spoke Spanish and 20% spoke English only*". A well written way of saying that would be "*30% of students spoke Spanish and 20% spoke English only*", as you just did.

Comment: @RayButterworth, I do agree, but I would also like to master other constructions, such as the one in question, and be able to say that 10% less/fewer/more people/dogs/robots do this than that. It can be helpful when writing long essays, for example for IELTS where such comparisons are necessary. I was sure that if I say something like '30% of cats eat fish and 10% fewer eat cheese,' it will be understood that 20% of cats eat cheese. My second question is whether I should say 'by 10% fewer' or simply "10% fewer.'

Comment: @ArsenyAleev says "*it will be understood that 20% of cats eat cheese*". By some people yes, and by others no (as demonstrated by the comments here). "*30% of cats eat fish and 10% fewer eat cheese*" is ambiguous and should be avoided. One should either say "30% … and 20% eat" or say "30% … and 27% eat", depending upon which is intended. — And "*be able to say that 10% less/fewer/more people/dogs/robots do this than that*". One can, but it must be clear what the 10% refers to. Consider if the original had said "300 of the thousand cats eat fish and 10% fewer eat cheese". That means 270 cats.

Comment: @RayButterworth, hm, thank you very much! I will try to discuss with my teacher why she is so concerned that it's necessary to introduce such structures.

Comment: @RayButterworth "The sentence ..." Yes, you are absolutely correct. **Very** embarrassing. I remember correcting it (after I formed it by editing the OP's original), but must have forgotten to save the edits. I've corrected it now.

Comment: @ArsenyAleev "How would you say ...": *"I'd say: "Out of 1000 students, 30% spoke Spanish and 20% spoke only English"*. Much shorter, and completely unambiguous.